# Per-table constants are not being substituted

Tags: emacs, spreadsheet, org-mode

Here is my table

```
|   | Name        | Vert    |  Horz | Area   | Cost | USD |
|---+-------------+---------+-------+--------+------+-----|
| $ | $price = 75 | $Hi=2.9 |       |        |      |     |
| # | Kitchen     | 4.160   | 3.630 | #ERROR |      |     |
|   |             |         |       |        |      |     |
|   |             |         |       |        |      |     |
|   |             |         |       |        |      |     |
    #+TBLFM: $5=$4*$Hi*2+$3*$Hi*2
```

Here is trace output:

```
Substitution history of formula
Orig:   $4*$Hi*2+$3*$Hi*2
$xyz->  $4*(#UNDEFINED_NAME)*2+$3*(#UNDEFINED_NAME)*2
@r$c->  $4*(#UNDEFINED_NAME)*2+$3*(#UNDEFINED_NAME)*2
$1->    (3.630)*(#UNDEFINED_NAME)*2+(4.160)*(#UNDEFINED_NAME)*2
       ---------^
Error:  #'s not allowed in this context
```

What's wrong? Why `$Hi` was not substituted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found it by myself. Here is wrong row, and the fixed row:

```
| $ | $price = 75 | $Hi=2.9 |       |        |      |     |
| $ |  price = 75 |  Hi=2.9 |       |        |      |     |
```